# JS events listeners memory consumption

Tags: javascript

Let's say I need to add the same event listener on each one of the following nodes:

```
function handler(e) { ... }

var clickMe = document.querySelectorAll('.click-me');

for (var i = 0; i < clickMe.length; i++) {
  clickMe[i].addEventListener('click', handler);
}
```

Will the memory grow in this case? If the answer is yes, why? I'm using the same function reference in each one of them. Is it because under the hood it does something like this:

```
class Div {
  listeners = {
    click: []
  }

  addEventListener(name, handler) {
    this.listeners[name].push(handler)
  }

}
```

And it causes the array to be bigger?

I know that we should use **event delegation**, but that's not my question. The question is, why in this case? (I don't talk about the dynamic DOM nodes that could be added over time, only about memory)

Comment: Just add one delegated event handler on the `document` instead.

Comment: That's not the question. I know what is event delegation.

Comment: Well if you know that, why would you want to add distinct listeners directly on a set of elements? (The direct answer to your question is "yes", but not very much memory.)

Comment: I want to understand why it's better, therefore this question.

Comment: If elements are removed over time and while listeners not then this could lead to a memory leak.

Comment: It would have been a good idea to mention that in the question in that case.

Comment: Are you seeing a problem? Doubt memory will be an issue here.

Comment: @TomO. mostly because it's a lot simpler.

Comment: Are you having a problem? If you're using the same function reference, memory shouldn't balloon, there would just be the overhead of adding the listener to the element.  The element should clean itself up on destruction.  The only issue would be if you make the same function over and over.  Though, even then, the unique functions should be cleaned up since nothing will point to them after destruction.  If you're asking if there is a leak, it depends on how exactly you make the functions and attach them.

Comment: I don't ask about a leak. I'm asking about the machine memory when there are 10000 nodes on the current page.

Comment: Every node will have a new listener added to it's listener list but they will all have a reference to the same callback.  So the memory would be `(1000 * sizeOfListenerRecord) + sizeOfFunction)`. I do not understand your question beyond this.  Memory will be used up whenever you create things and you are creating 1000 new listeners and possibly 1 function.

Comment: When you say "creating 1000 new listeners", it's like the pseudo-code I added?